# Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded router dom

Tags: reactjs

tengo una pagina que cuenta con un login,registro y reestablecerr contraseña y otra que es la pagina principal, estoy usando firebase y redux, ya logro registrar usuarios e iniciar sesion y guardar los datos en el state del redux, ahora quiero proteger las rutas, tengo un state donde se cambia true cuando se encontro un usuario y a false cuando se cierra sesion, tengo un archivo de rutas publicas y otros privadas que segun yo deberia funcionar, pero me sale el error

```
Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

estoy usando react router dom.
Este es el componente principal AppRouter.js

```
const AppRouter = () => {
    
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [checking, setChecking] = useState(true);

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
        const auth = getAuth();
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) =>{
            if(user?.uid) {
                console.log('Si existe un usuario')
                dispatch(login(user.displayName, user.uid));
                setAuthenticated(true);
            }else{
                console.log('No existe un usuario')
                setAuthenticated(false);
            }
            setChecking(false)
        })
    }, [authenticated, setAuthenticated])


    if(checking){
        return (
            <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold">Espere...</h1>
        )
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>

                {/* <Route path="/"
                    element={<PrivateRoutes isAuthenticated={authenticated}
                    element={<DiaryHomePage />} />} 
                /> 
 
                <Route path="*"
                    element={<PublicRoutes isAuthenticated={authenticated}
                    element={<AuthRouters />}  />} 
                />  */}


                {/* <Route path='/' element={ <DiaryHomePage />} />
                <Route path='*' element={ <AuthRouters />} /> */}
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

PublicRoutes.js

```
const PublicRoutes = (isAuthenticated, element) => {
  return (
      (isAuthenticated)
      ? <Navigate to='/'/>
      : element
  )
};
```

PrivateRoutes

```
const PrivateRoutes = ({isAuthenticated, element}) => {
  return(
      (isAuthenticated)
      ? element
      : <Navigate to='/login' />
  )
};
```

En AppRouter tengo un estado(authenticated) que su valor inicial es false,que mediante el metodo onAuthStateChanged verifico si hay un usuario autenticado, si lo hay, lo cambio a true y este me muestra el componente pricipal, al estar en el componente principal ya no puedo entrar a las rutas publicas(login,register,reset), ya que hay un usuario autenticado, al cerrar sesion me cambia el estado a false y es aqui donde se sale este error

componente donde tengo el boton logout que me cambia el estado a false y elimina la informacion del usuario auntenticado

```
const Sidebar = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleLogout= () => {
        dispatch(startLogout())
    }

    const {showMain} = useSelector(state => state.sidebar)
    console.log(showMain)

    const hiddenSidebar = () => {
        dispatch(closeSidebar())
    }

    return (
        <div className={ showMain ? 'left-0 content-sidebar w-full  flex flex-col bg-slate-800 pb-2 h-screen fixed z-10 duration-300 md-static' : "w-full -left-full fixed duration-300 bg-slate-800 z-20 flex flex-col h-screen md:static"}>
        
            <div className="diary-sidebar-navbar flex justify-between px-3 pt-3 text-white font-medium ">
                
                <h2>LuisPv</h2>
                <button 
                    className="hover:text-gray-300"
                    onClick={handleLogout}
                >Logout</button>
                
                <div className="icon-hidden-sidebar absolute left-2/4 -translate-x-1/2 md:hidden">
                    <i 
                        className="fas fa-times text-lg cursor-pointer"
                        onClick={ hiddenSidebar }
                    ></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="diary-sidebar-new-entry text-white text-center pt-12">
                <button className="">
                    <i className="far fa-calendar-plus text-7xl duration-500 hover:scale-125 hover:duration-500"></i>
                </button>
                <h1 className="font-semibold pt-2 text-2xl">New Note</h1>
                
            </div>

            <DiaryEntries />
        </div>

    )
}
```

acciones que mando al reducer para cambiar el estado

```
export const startLogout = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const auth = getAuth();
        signOut(auth)
            .then(() => {
                dispatch(logout())
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }
}


const logout = () => {
    return {
        type: types.logout
    }
}
```

Comment: Comenta todo el método `onAuthStateChanged` y prueba el `useEffect` únicamente con `setAuthenticated(true)` y `setChecking(false)`.

Comment: y como lo regreso a true?, el metodo como que me busca si existe un usuario, al presionar el boton login guarda el usuario y si existe me cambia el estado authenticated a true, al cerrar sesion lo devuelve a false, y con esto me deberia mostrar las rutas, al hacer click en login si me lleva al componente principal, al cerrar sesion, es donde me marca este error

Comment: Si la intencion era ver si `onAuthStateChanged` estaba causando el problema, ya que revise la lógica de ese `useEffect` y todo parece bien; pero entonces dices que es al **cerrar sesión**, por favor muestra como se cierra la sesión y menciona eso en la pregunta, parece ser un problema al desmontar algún componente.

Comment: si ya agregue el componente donde cierro sesion, y donde hago las acciones para cerrar la sesion